# Knockout.js binding 2D table with rowspan

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, knockout.js

*The question is also posted on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/40276/35742), but I considered posting it here as well because the community that is likely to help is bigger here and the topic is still relevant.*

The app I'm working on should allows it's users to create tables. I have a view in which users are able to create a table. They should be able to define here the table's columns. The columns that the user adds will be part from some predefined types of columns: BusinessFields, SourceKeys, SourceAttrs,...; At the same time columns should have some other proprieties that define the value they will contain: minlength, minValue, defaultValue,...

These tables have to have a format(at least a column for the SourceKeys and TargetKeys categories), but this format is not so restrictive. The image will help to describe the point:

[image]

I have made it work as you see in the image, but I don't like how I've made the bindings. My code structure also reduces the flexibility (For example: It would be much more difficult to add a click binding for a row).

**JavaScript:**

```
//column definition
function Column(columnName, minLength, maxLength, minValue, maxValue, reg_ex, role, order, defaultValue) {
    var self = {};
    self.name = ko.observable(columnName || 'new column');
    self.minLength = ko.observable(minLength || null);
    self.maxLength = ko.observable(maxLength || null);
    self.minValue = ko.observable(minValue || null);
    self.maxValue = ko.observable(maxValue || null);
    self.reg_exp = ko.observable(reg_ex || null);
    self.role = ko.observable(role ? role : 1);
    self.order = ko.observable(order || null);
    self.defaultValue = ko.observable(defaultValue || null);
    return self;
}

//table definition
function Table() {
    var self = {};
    self.tableName = ko.observable('New table');
    self.tableDescription = ko.observable('description');
    self.businessFields = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.sourceKeys = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.sourceAttr = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.targetKeys = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.targetAttr = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.attrFields = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.technicalFields = ko.observableArray([]);
    return self;
}
//the table
var newTable = ko.observable(Table());
//adding columns to the table
newTable.businessFields.push(Column('col_1'));
```

**HTML:** (only enough tho get the idea)

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Min Length</th>
                        <th>Max Length</th>
                        <th>Min Value</th>
                        <th>Max Value</th>
                        <th>Regular Expr</th>
                        <th>Default Value</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="with: newTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td data-bind="attr: { rowspan: function(){ if(businessFields().length == 0) return 1; else return businessFields().length; }()}">Business fields</td>
                        <!-- ko if: businessFields().length > 0 -->
                        <td><strong data-bind="text: businessFields()[0].name"></strong></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: businessFields()[0].minLength"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: businessFields()[0].maxLength"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: businessFields()[0].minValue"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: businessFields()[0].maxValue"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: businessFields()[0].reg_exp"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: businessFields()[0].defaultValue"></span></td>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </tr>
                    <!-- ko foreach:  businessFields -->
                    <!-- ko if: $index() !== 0 -->
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong data-bind="text: name"></strong></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: minLength"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: maxLength"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: minValue"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: maxValue"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: reg_exp"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: defaultValue"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- /ko -->

                    <tr>
                        <td data-bind="attr: { rowspan: function(){ if(sourceKeys().length == 0) return 1; else return sourceKeys().length; }()}">Source keys</td>
                        <!-- ko if: sourceKeys().length > 0 -->
                        <td><strong data-bind="text: sourceKeys()[0].name"></strong></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: sourceKeys()[0].minLength"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: sourceKeys()[0].maxLength"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: sourceKeys()[0].minValue"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: sourceKeys()[0].maxValue"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: sourceKeys()[0].reg_exp"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: sourceKeys()[0].defaultValue"></span></td>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </tr>
                    <!-- ko foreach:  sourceKeys -->
                    <!-- ko if: $index() !== 0 -->
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong data-bind="text: name"></strong></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: minLength"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: maxLength"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: minValue"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: maxValue"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: reg_exp"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: defaultValue"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- /ko -->

                    ......
                    ......
```

Do you have any ideas on how could I bind to represent this 2D table? The JavaScript structure is not a restriction, because I was thinking that storing the columns in different arrays is not a good idea for dynamic data. Maybe each column should have a variable that would identify from which category takes part. Therefore, the `newTable` object should be restructured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a ColumnType object like this:

```
//column definition
function Column(columnName, minLength, maxLength, minValue, maxValue, reg_ex, role, order, defaultValue) {
    var self = {};
    self.name = ko.observable(columnName || 'new column');
    self.minLength = ko.observable(minLength || null);
    self.maxLength = ko.observable(maxLength || null);
    self.minValue = ko.observable(minValue || null);
    self.maxValue = ko.observable(maxValue || null);
    self.reg_exp = ko.observable(reg_ex || null);
    self.role = ko.observable(role ? role : 1);
    self.order = ko.observable(order || null);
    self.defaultValue = ko.observable(defaultValue || null);
    return self;
}

function ColumnType(name) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.columns = ko.observableArray([]);
}
//table definition
function Table() {
    var self = {};
    self.tableName = ko.observable('New table');
    self.tableDescription = ko.observable('description');
    self.columnTypes = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.addColumn = function(columnTypeName, column) {
        console.log('adding column of type ' + columnTypeName);
        var columnType = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.columnTypes(), function(item) {
            return item.name() == columnTypeName;
        });

        if(!columnType) {
            console.log('Column type ' + columnTypeName + ' does not exist\n Creating new ColumnType object');
            columnType = new ColumnType(columnTypeName);  
            self.columnTypes.push(columnType);
        }

        columnType.columns.push(column);
    }

    return self;
}

// Here's my data model
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    //the table
    self.newTable = ko.observable(new Table());
};

var VM = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(VM); 

//adding columns to the table
VM.newTable().addColumn('businessFields', new Column('col_1'));
VM.newTable().addColumn('businessFields', new Column('col_2'));
VM.newTable().addColumn('test', new Column('col_3'));
```

And the html:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Min Length</th>
                    <th>Max Length</th>
                    <th>Min Value</th>
                    <th>Max Value</th>
                    <th>Regular Expr</th>
                    <th>Default Value</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="with: newTable">
                <!-- ko foreach: columnTypes -->
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: name, attr: { rowspan: function(){ if(columns().length == 0) return 1; else return columns().length; }()}"></td>
                    <!-- ko if: columns().length > 0 -->
                    <td><strong data-bind="text: columns()[0].name"></strong></td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: columns()[0].minLength"></span></td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: columns()[0].maxLength"></span></td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: columns()[0].minValue"></span></td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: columns()[0].maxValue"></span></td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: columns()[0].reg_exp"></span></td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: columns()[0].defaultValue"></span></td>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </tr>
                <!-- ko foreach:  columns -->
                <!-- ko if: $index() !== 0 -->
                <tr>
                    <td><strong data-bind="text: name"></strong></td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: minLength"></span></td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: maxLength"></span></td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: minValue"></span></td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: maxValue"></span></td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: reg_exp"></span></td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: defaultValue"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </tbody>
</table>
```

[See the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sU4gh/)

Comment: and how would I bind it to get the structure like in the image?

Comment: Thanks. That is a bit better than what I had, but I will leave the question open for some other(better) approaches (maybe a custom binding, maybe 2 tables that are next to each other).